# Is density proportional to specific heat capacity?

Tags: thermodynamics, density

Is a substance with a higher density than other necessarily have a higher specific heat?

Comment: In general, yes. Specific heat capacity is proportional to carrier density which is proportional to atomic density.

Comment: In general, no. https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Heat_capacity&oldid=750553453 There are such things as degrees of freedom which frequently overrule density.

Comment: Indeed, and the highest density matter we know of - in neutron stars - has an extremely *low* heat capacity.

Comment: To add to what @GyroGearloose said, the specific heat capacity is reckoned per unit mass (or per mole) of the material.  For an ideal gas, for example, it is independent of the gas density.

Answer (score -1):

Basically, this is a summary of the above comments, in case they are removed  later.

How can a substance store energy say heat, entering the system?

1. The molecules and/or atoms can move (as units) in 3 different directions.
2. Molecules, other than diatomic types, can rotate in 3 different directions.
3. The atoms in molecules can oscillate at higher frequencies.

I cannot comment, due to ignorance on the subject, what extra degrees of freedom may be available to highly compressed, dense  matter.

But sticking with normal matter, these above d.o.f. are all based on quadratic terms.

Equipartion, which is the term for the equal division of energy as described above, does not include aspects such as  electronic states, nuclear states, which may also store energy without increasing the temperature.

I think the answer comes down to the makeup and physical condition of specific substances rather than an overall heading of increased density implies a higher/lower SHC.

I looked through the web and there seem to be the same type of comments regarding yes/no,  as illustrated above on the site linked below: (just to illustrate how even **one** "ordinary" material can vary depending on it's composition)

[Concrete and variables affecting SHC](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Is_there_a_correlation_between_material_density_and_specific_heat)

> An experimental study was performed for producing new lightweight concretes. Density and compressive strength decreased, and insulation properties improved. The reductions in thermal conductivity and diffusivity reached to 82% and 74%. a b s t r a c t In this study, experimental investigation is performed for producing new cement-based with relatively high strength, low density and good thermal properties for energy efficient buildings. Different types of concretes containing silica fume (SF), superplasticizer (SP) and air-entrained admixtures are prepared with a constant water–cement ratio, and normal aggregates replaced by lightweight aggregates (LWAs) including pumice (PA), expanded perlite (EPA) and rubber aggregates (RA) at different volume fractions of 10%, 20%, 30%, 40% and 50%. 102 samples with different materials and compositions are produced, and their characteristics are tested in accordance with ASTM and EN standards. Based on the experimental results, equations are presented to determine the relation between the thermophysical properties of composite samples. The investigation revealed that the addition of PA, EPA and RA reduced the material bulk density and compressive strength, and improved the insulation characteristics of the composite con-cretes. Furthermore, it was found out that the reductions in thermal conductivity and diffusivity of the produced samples reached to 82% and 74%, respectively.